# Analyse hardware documentation and output human readable report

Tags: windows, java, hardware, documentation-viewer

I need to make custom hardware documentation available for laymen to read. I'm working with decades old hardware that comes with a custom documentation system. So eg. different systems will have different lights. The documentation could say something like

```
LIGHTS = RV46
```

This would then need to be translated to eg. 'strong lights installed'. In addition to this, the software would also have to perform some boolean functions. So if, say, strong lights and a strong motor but a small power supply it would have to give the output 'insufficient power supply'.

Because the hardware documentation is custom I would obviously have to write the logic myself. What I'm looking for is software that does all of the stuff around like GUI, file handling, installation etc. More specifically there would need to be a way of loading in the hardware documentation .txt file, an area to display the output messages and a way to run the program easily (not command line).

The closest thing I've been able to find are log parser applications, but they all seem very optimized for handling vast amounts of data and software documentation rather than hardware documentation.

Any recommendations are appreciated, no matter how far fetched or work-aroundish. Java package recommendations are also fine. I would much rather contribute to/use an existing project, instead of writing the thing from scratch just for it to be unsupported in 3 years. Only restriction is that it has to run in Windows.